# Verification of a general solution of a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

**Question:**

$$y''+(y')^2=0$$
Verify that $y_1=1$ and $y_2=\ln(x)$ are linearly independent solutions of the equation on any interval to the right of the origin. Is $c_1+c_2\ln(x)$ the general solution. If not, why not?

**My attempt:**
Direct substitution into the DE shows both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions.
To show they are linearly independent either by ratio or by the Wronskian:
$$W(1,\ln(x)) = \frac{1}{x} \neq 0 \space\space\space\space\space \forall x>0$$
So since both solutions are linearly independent then the general solution should be: $$y=c_1+c_2\ln(x)$$

However, substituting this into the original differential equation, I get:

$$-\frac{c_2}{x^2}+\frac{c_2^2}{x^2} = \frac{c_2^2-c_2}{x^2} \neq 0$$
So why does not it satisfy the original equation?

Moreover, solving the DE using reduction of order, I get: $$y=\ln(x-c_1)+c_2$$ as the general solution (which works). So how to answer the "why not question"?

Comment: *Hint:* That is not a *linear* DE.

Comment: Yes, but I used $p=y'$ so it becomes linear first order via this substitution.
Or do you mean it is not a linear second order DE, and so the general solution of second order homogeneous equation does not work? Oh that makes a lot of sense. So the only way so far to solve it via first order techniques right? Thanks @MartinR

Comment: Even $p' + p^2=0$ isn't linear, so it's hard to interpret your comment.

Comment: Let $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ 
Then, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=p\frac{dp}{dy} $$
Implying $p\frac{dp}{dy}+p^2=0 $ so $\frac{dp}{dy}+p=0$ which is linear?

Comment: That is for $p$ as function of $y$, not for $y$ or $y'$ as function of $x$. You get the non-linear equation $y'=Ce^{-y}$.

Comment: Yes I meant the equation of p and its derivative should be linear. Sorry for the confusion, I should have been more clear.
Anyhow, now I see why the general solution does not work & a way to solve it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is interesting is a switch of variable to get $x''-x'=0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, sorry I do not see the substitution that yields this equation, can you elaborate? As it seems interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is not linear, so the superposition principle does not apply. Linear independence is thus the wrong property. One could explore for functional independence, but there the search space of multivariate functions is much larger than the space of coefficient tuples.

Multiply with $e^y$ to get $$(e^y)''=0,$$ which has the solutions $$y(x)=\ln(c_1x+c_0).$$ You can find the claimed solutions among them.

Answer (score 2):

First $y_1 = c_1$ is a solution for $y''+(y')^2=0$ but $y_2=c_2\ln x$ is a particular solution because $c_2$ should be $c_2=1$. The ODE is not linear and the superposition property can't be used. Calling $u=y'$ we have

$$
u'+u^2=0
$$

which is separable with solution

$$
u = \frac{1}{x-c_1}\Rightarrow y = \int u dx = \ln(x-c_1)+c_2
$$